# How to change function from using WordPress medium_large to the original file uploaded?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am currently trying to create a custom image size for **WordPress**. I am uploading my full size image (**1,000px by 1,000px**) using the **Media Library**, and trying to use the `function`'s below in my `functions.php` file.

As you can see, I am trying to save another version that is exactly **50%** of the original image's `width` and `height`. The `function` below *is* saving a new version, but it is using WordPress' `medium_large` (**768px by 768px**) image, which results in my image being saved at **384px by 384px** instead of the desired **500px by 500px**.

I tried changing WordPress' default **`medium_large`** size to **2000px by 2000px**, but then the `function` below switched to using WordPress' **`thumbnail`** (**150px by 150px**) image, resulting in a **75px by 75px** image.

How do I get the code below to use the **`original`** image, not one of WordPress' created image sizes (**`medium_large`**, **`thumbnail`**, etc)?

```html
<?php
add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'half_size_attachment_meta', 10, 2);

function half_size_attachment_meta($metadata, $attachment_id) {
  foreach($metadata as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
      foreach($value as $image => $attr) {
        if (is_array($attr))
          half_size_create_images(get_attached_file($attachment_id), $attr['width'], $attr['height'], true);
      }
    }
  }
  return $metadata;
}

function half_size_create_images($file, $width, $height, $crop = false) {
  if ($width || $height) {
    $resized_file = wp_get_image_editor($file);
    if (!is_wp_error($resized_file)) {
      $filename = $resized_file - > generate_filename($width.
        'x'.$height.
        '-sml');

      $resized_file - > resize($width * 0.5, $height * 0.5, $crop);
      $resized_file - > save($filename);

      $info = $resized_file - > get_size();

      return array(
        'file' => wp_basename($filename),
        'width' => $info['width'],
        'height' => $info['height'],
      );
    }
  }
  return false;
}
?>
```

**Edit**: I am not looking to use `add_image_size` / `the_post_thumbnail` within the functions.php file. This doesn't force the creation of images, and doesn't allow for percentage based values.

Answer (score 0):

Create your new image size with builtin WP function `add_image_size` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

then call it with `the_post_thumbnail` function
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/

Comment: `add_image_size` does not allow you to specify `%` values. I'm also looking to force the creation of the image, which again, `add_image_size` doesn't allow for.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/fly-dynamic-image-resizer/ creates image sizes on the fly. Open up their php and use it in your project or use the plugin. There are no percentage based size generators, you would set an appropriate size and use CSS to size your image. You can use srcset too: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/

Comment: @Christina I am not looking for a plugin. I am specifically looking for help with my existing functions, which are using `%` based values just fine, it's just not referencing the original image in my code.